# Failed to start domain SC-1

Tags: css, virtualbox

I am trying to bring common base architecture controller for my ovs setup on the esxi box sles linux os . when i try to bring up my controller i am getting the following error. Could you please help me out.

"unsupported configuration: Domain requires KVM, but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in the host BIOS, and host configuration is setup to load the kvm modules."

### Steps followed to bring up my controller

linux-u96x:~/cbavms/products # virsh define SC-1.xml
Domain SC-1 defined from SC-1.xml

linux-u96x:~/cbavms/products # virsh start SC-1
error: Failed to start domain SC-1
error: unsupported configuration: Domain requires KVM, but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in the host BIOS, and host configuration is setup to load the kvm modules.

linux-u96x:~/cbavms/products #

Answer (score 0):

## KVM Software tools should be on the controller

patterns-sles-kvm_server - KVM Host Server   12-58.8

patterns-sles-kvm_server-32bit - KVM Host Server

patterns-sles-kvm_tools - KVM Virtualization Host and tools

patterns-sles-kvm_tools-32bit - KVM Virtualization Host and tools

qemu-kvm - Kernel-based Virtual Machine

virt-v2v - Convert a virtual machine to run on KVM

yast2-vm - Configure Hypervisor and Tools for Xen and KVM

## check the hardware requirement as mentioned below:

1.1. Hardware Requirements¶
Currently, SUSE only supports KVM full virtualization on x86_64 hosts. KVM is designed around hardware virtualization

features included in AMD (AMD-V) and Intel (VT-x) CPUs. It supports virtualization features of chipsets, and PCI devices,

such as an I/O Memory Mapping Unit (IOMMU) and Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)).

You can test whether your CPU supports hardware virtualization with the following command:

egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
If this command returns no output, your processor either does not support hardware virtualization, or this feature has been

disabled in the BIOS.

The following Web site identifies processors which support hardware virtualization:

## how to enable the vx-t in virtual machine :

https://forum.ivorde.com/kvm-nested-in-vmware-esxi-5-5-enable-guest-hypervisor-vmx-svm-flags-without-vsphere-web-client-

t19773.html

GO to the VMS vmdk folders and edit .vmx file and add the following flag in that file and save it.

vhv.enable = "TRUE"

Follow the commands below to restart the VM and reboot the machine.

/vmfs/volumes/53071ba5-6f9682d4-5898-002590883ef6/SLES 12 VM # vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep -i sles
15     SLES-82                [datastore1] SLES 1/SLES 1.vmx                               sles11_64Guest   vmx-08
59     SLES 12 VM             [datastore1] SLES 12 VM/SLES 12 VM.vmx                       sles11_64Guest   vmx-08
/vmfs/volumes/53071ba5-6f9682d4-5898-002590883ef6/SLES 12 VM # vim-cmd vmsvc/reload 59
/vmfs/volumes/53071ba5-6f9682d4-5898-002590883ef6/SLES 12 VM #